# How to design subscription based api service with multiple api keys using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, api-design

Suppose I have an API that provides some services. The users must have at least one api key to make requests. Lets say that you get 1,000 request per month for free and if you want more, you pay a monthly subscription.

How would you store this business model using mongodb and apply rate limits based on monthly request count?

I'm using node.js

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to approach this, so here are my 2 cents.

I've done something similar what you're after using **[Stripe](https://stripe.com)** (for managing Plans and Payments processing) and **MongoDb** (for storing User related data). It may not be exactly what you want, but might inspire some ideas.

**On MongoDB**

MongoDB will keep count of you user API requests. This count can be used for accepting / declining requests depending on your business rules.

Assuming you have a **Users collection** on MongoDb (or similar), you should make provisions to keep "count" of successful requests made by your users. This can be a simple counter attribute with an associated timestamp attribute (so that you know when it should be reset i.e. after a month). Unless you have valid reasons, **avoid counting failed requests** (i.e. API requests that result in **4XX** or **5XX** responses)

Essentially, upon a successful user API request, check if the counter is still valid (i.e. within the month) and increment the count - if a month had already lapsed, start the count from 0. You can use the "[$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)" operator to increment the number, rather than incrementing them yourself.

As to how it should be represented in MongoDB, it can be something like this (within the User document):

```
{
  ...
  "apiUsage" : {
    "requestsThisMonth" : 850,
    "updatedAt": "2019-11-21T10:10:10.100Z"
  }
}
```

**On Stripe**

Stripe will be used to keep a record of the number of checks made during a period, and charge your users accordingly.

Stripe provides means for creating [Pricing Plans](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/products-and-plans), which you can then associate to your users. In this case, you can create a monthly [Metered Usage](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing) plan, with **tiered pricing**. Your tiered pricing can be set so that the first 1,000 units (i.e. API requests) are free ($0.00). You can start charging them once they've exceeded a 1000 units.

Once a customer is subscribed to a plan, you can use the Stripe API to increment usage.

**High Level Flow**

1. User makes an API request
2. Your service checks MongoDB and decides whether it wants to satisfy or reject the request. You can decline for reasons such as the users payment card has expired, or they've exceeded your upper limit threshold, or etc.
3. Your service satisfies / rejects the request
4. Increment count in MongoDB, if request is satisfied
5. Increment count in Stripe, if request is satisfied

This is obviously an oversimplified view, but hope it gives you an idea how it can be done.

**Note** - besides the rate limiting specifed above, you may want to consider having a mechanism for proper API rate limiting, to prevent your service from being bombarded with requests it can't handle. This type of mechanism should be done at an API gateway level, as opposed to doing it yourself using MongoDB. For instance, if you're using AWS to host your API, they provide you with means to configure rate limits.